# Store variables out of the bundle in osgi

Tags: osgi, activiti, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I have one question about blueprint in OSGI Bundles. I bundle activiti in one, but there are some configurations that have to be made in the blueprint to get it work. i don't want to compile the bundle new for every time I change those settings. is it possible to store them out out the blueprint to change it needing only to restart the bundle?

```
 <bean id="configuration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.JtaProcessEngineConfiguration"
      ext:field-injection="true">
    <property name="databaseType" value="h2"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true"/>
    <property name="transactionsExternallyManaged" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultCamelContext" value="defaultContext"/>
    <property name="mailServerHost" value="smtp.googlemail.com"/>
    <property name="mailServerUsername" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="mailServerPassword" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="mailServerPort" value="465"/>
    <property name="useSSL" value="true" />
    <property name="useTLS" value="true" />
    <property name="mailServerDefaultFrom" value="senderadress"/>
</bean>
```

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In OSGi you use the configuration admin spec for your configs. In Apache Karaf it allows to store configs in files in the etc directory.

To inject them into blueprint you use the blueprint-cm namespace.
[See this tutorial](http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/G4Be) how to use it.